# How do I add style and html to flash error message in my controller in Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have this in my UserController.rb

```
           def create
                @user = User.new(user_params)
                if @user.save
                    sign_in @user

                    flash[:success] = "Welcome to the TurnKii!"

                    redirect_to @user
                    # Handle a successful save.
                else


                    redirect_to signup_url
                    flash[:error] = @user.errors.empty? ? "Error" :  @user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence

                end
            end
```

the code works right now, but I would like to add some styling to my flash error message, it just shows up on the top of the page as bare text in 1 sentence.

I dont mind the sentence, but I would like to add some styling to this and semantic tags as well.

Currently its showing up on the page inside a

```
 <div class="alert alert-danger">Error Sentence here</div>
```

i have tried to style that in my css, but its not rendering. I would like to have something like this(or similar)  for my flash message

```
                    flash[:error] = @user.errors.empty? ? "Error" :  <h1 class=alert-danger >@user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence</h1>
```

but anytime i add anything in there, I run into errors.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Anything related to the layout or format of the display on a page should be put in a View. In this case, the flash messages are printed out in `layouts/application.html.erb` (or `.html.haml`)

Comment: yea I understand. Its not good to mix MVC. I am still learning rails, there are alot of things I dont know how to do, I also have nested resources in my app. So making changes like that is hard for me. But I am learning as I go and refactoring my old code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try add css changes in your application.css.scss file. That will automatically loaded in all the views. But if you still want flash message in html then you can use below code.

```
flash[:error] = @user.errors.empty? ? "Error" :  "<h1 class='alert-danger' >#{@user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}</h1>".html_safe
```

Comment: I believe this approach leaves you open to xss attack since If the invalid input provided contains markup/script tags it will render it on the page since it's marked safe.